# What permissions do I need to get the request digest of a SharePoint site using SharePoint's REST API?

Tags: sharepoint

What permissions do I need to get the request digest of a SharePoint site using SharePoint's REST API?

If I have view only access to the site but I have contribute access to a list on the site can I still get the request digest?

Comment: Maybe https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, by default it is required for user to have the `Use Remote Interfaces` permission to access REST API and get the Request Digest. However, this requirement can be changed (e.g. in order to enable anonymous users to access REST API). More about that: [What Every Developer Needs to Know About SharePoint Apps, CSOM, and Anonymous Publishing Sites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites/)

Comment: Is there a way to check if I have the Use Remote Interfaces permission through the api? So far I just see how to get the permission levels like "view only", "contributr", etc.

Comment: You  mean you want to check it programatically (using a REST API) or just check from the UI whether you can use REST or not?

Comment: Programmatically through the REST API. Something like site/_api/permissions. But actually it sounds like you're saying if you have access to the API that means you have the Use Remote Interfaces permission already. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. If you want to check it for another user, then it's not a trivial task, but certainly can be done: http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/checking-user-permissions-from-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/